merge [comedians-in-cars] and [comedians-in-cars-getting-coffee]?
comedians-in-cars 1 question:

Can someone explain the Acura "I sell cars, you sell you" ads?

comedians-in-cars-getting-coffee 1 question:

Who is Jerry ranting about in the Bridget Everett episode of Comedians in Cars Getting Coffee?

Merge?
What would be a good Wiki excerpt (usage guideline)?

Merged the tag, not familiar with the show to write an excerpt. A good Wiki excerpt should not be copy pasted and explain the show or usage to future users well.
